# Get all the products of an array

Tags: algorithm, combinations

How can I calculate all the products of an array and return two products for each combination?

Array:

```
[2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Output:

```
1, 2*2*3*4
2, 2*3*4
2*2, 3*4
2*2*3, 4
2*2*4, 3
2*3, 2*4
```

I hope my output contains all of them. Any ideas, pseudocode, code are welcomed.

Comment: why do `2*3, 2*4` and `2*4, 2*3` both appear in the output, but `2*2, 3*4` is there while `3*4, 2*2` is not?

Comment: @lazydog it was a mistake, sorry.

Comment: You could just enumerate the numbers from 0 to 2^n and use their binary representation to determine which numbers go into the first and which into the second product, and use a set to weed out duplicates.

Comment: @tobias_k: that's pretty inefficient if there are lots of repeated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the factors are repeated, you need to take their multiplicities into account to avoid repeating some products.

Sort the array if needed and count the multiplicities (consecutive equal values).

Then, assuming k distinct values with respective multiplicities Mk, you will emulate k nested loops, each from 0 to Mk inclusive. For this emulation, consider an array of counters all initialized to 0. Then increment the first counter, and when it reaches its maximum value, reset it and carry to the next counter. If the next counter reaches its maximum, reset it and carry to the next...

Use these counters as exponents of the factors and compute the product. The second number is the product of all factors divided by the first number.

E.g.

```
Values:         2, 3, 4
Multiplicities: 2, 1, 1

Counters:
  000
  100
  200
  010
  110
  210
  001
  101
  201
  011
  111
  211

First numbers:
  1
  2
  2²
  3
  2.3
  2²3
  4
  2.4
  2²4
  3.4
  2.3.4
  2²3.4

Second numbers = 2²3.4 / First numbers
```

The total number of product pairs equals the product of the multiplicities plus one, (M1+1)(M2+1)...(Mk+1).

Comment: It seems that OP does not want to produce both A,B and B,A. That could be achieved by ensuring that A <= B (lexicographically, not as a product), which slightly alters the enumeration strategy.

Comment: @rici: can you spot any A,B / B,A pair in my enumeration ?

Comment: First number: 1 second number 2 2 3 4 / first number 2 2 3 4 second number 1. Based on your enumeration and the formula you provide for computing second numbers.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that. A possible fix is indeed to check that the counters form a number which is lower than the number formed by the complementary. Maybe there is a way to enumerate them directly without this test.

Comment: You can simply stop enumeration after reaching half of the total number of product pairs to avoid repeated partitions.

Comment: @lazydog: Of course that is true (for this enumeration order, anyway) but it is only useful if you have some way to know when you've reached the middle. (That's not horribly complicated -- actually it's pretty simple -- but I'm not sure that it is obvious.) (Personally, I'd start at the middle and work down until I reached 0. That makes the completion check cheaper.)

Comment: @rici Well, the answer includes a direct formula for the total number of (multiset) combinations / ordered product pairs. One need only account for the possibility of an odd number of results.  Also, if i'm not mistaken, i believe it will work for any enumeration order?

Comment: @lazydog: you need an enumeration order where the complement of a multiset is not in the same half as the multiset. There are obviously enumeration orders which don't satisfy that requirement, such as the zigzag enumeration which interleaves forward and backward lexicographic enumeration until they converge. (Named after google protobuf zigzag encoding :) )

Comment: @rici Ah, of course, you're right. I was being myopic. All the simple recursive procedures I was thinking of--as well as the approach in this answer--would always have that property.